# Problem creating a Salesforce User via SCIMv2 when specifying ContactId

Tags: salesforce, scim2

I am using the Salesforce REST APIs to create a Contact and then an associated User. If I allow the creation of a User (via SCIMv2) to create an Account and Contact automatically (as details at [link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.identity_scim_rest_api.htm&type=5)), the creation works. Unfortunately, I need to populate a custom field in the Contact and must create it separately.

The [link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.identity_scim_rest_api.htm&type=5) also states that I can include the AccountId and ContactId to prevent the auto-creation. To do this I include the specified Account and Contact in the SCIMv2 JSON as shown below.

```
{
  "schemas" : [ "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User", "urn:salesforce:schemas:extension:external:2.0", "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User" ],
  "userName" : "fred.bloggs@example.com",
  "name" : {
    "familyName" : "Bloggs",
    "givenName" : "Fred"
  },
  "emails" : [ {
    "type" : "work",
    "primary" : true,
    "value" : "fred.bloggs@example.com"
  } ],
  "preferredLanguage" : "en_US",
  "locale" : "en_AU",
  "timezone" : "Australia/Hobart",
  "active" : true,
  "entitlements" : [ {
    "value" : "00e5j000000md3VAAQ"
  } ],
  "urn:salesforce:schemas:extension:external:2.0" : {
    "contactId" : "0039D00000JBLfvQAH",
    "accountId" : "0019D00000OkFMYQA3"
  }
}
```

When I make this request I get an error response from Salesforce:

```
Response Status:400 - Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATES_DETECTED, You're creating a duplicate record. We recommend you use an existing record instead.
```

Since there is definitely not a User object already in the system for this user, I am assuming it's trying to create the Contact again and failing.

Any help to understand what is happening and what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue. Instead of using urn:salesforce:schemas:extension:external:2.0 Please use below code : urn:salesforce:schemas:extension:2.0:external I found this in response of schema api(get). Below points need to be taken care:

Do not provide the contactid with which already user is tagged.
First you can try simply by providing only accountid then it will create user with new contact but under same account.